# Как вывести все элементы массивов, используя рекурсию?

Tags: c, массивы, рекурсия

Вызывая рекурсивную функцию, передаю ей начало массива и количество элементов:

```
Print(dodanok[i], elem);
```

А вот с самой функцией рекурсии беда:

```
int Print(int dodanok[], int elem)
{
    if (elem > i) {
        printf("t%i+ ", dodanok[i]);
        return Print(dodanok[i], elem--);
    }
    if (elem == i)
        return 0;
}
```

Кто-нибудь подскажите, пожалуйста, как это правильно реализовать.

Comment: А где в параметрах i? Можно убрать i, но тогда количество элементов надо уменьшать (и не постдекрементом, а предекрементом, до вызова Print.

    int Print (int dodanok[], int elem) { 
      if (elem>0) {
         printf("\t%i+ ",dodanok[0]);
         return Print(++dodanok, --elem);
      }
      return 0;
    }

Answer (score 4):

Например, так

```
void Print (int arr [], unsigned len) {
    if (len == 0 ) {
        putchar ('\n'); 
        return;
    }
    printf ("\t%i+", *arr);
    Print (arr+1, len-1);
}
```

Comment: Тогда принимаем ответ

Comment: Может лучше наверно `len <= 0` ?